# Безопасно ли удалить файл логов general_log.txt?

Tags: mysql

При выполнении запроса со вставкой данных большого объёма *SQLyog* начал вылетать с ошибкой:

> not enough memory application terminated

В связи с этим я решила почистить логи. 
И возник вопрос: безопасным ли будет удаление файла логов **general_log.txt**? И связан ли этот файл каким-либо образом с таблицей MySQL **mysql.general_log**?

**UPD**

Я выполнила команду:

```
TRUNCATE table mysql.general_log
```

и таблица **mysql.general_log** очистилась, но размер файла не изменился...
И к тому же если раньше этот файл открывался, то теперь при попытке его открыть я получаю ошибку:

> Нет доступа, или файл general_log.txt уже используется.

Comment: Удалить вроде безопасно, но наверно лучше его вообще отключить в настройках?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется, я нашла выход. После выполнения команды:

```
TRUNCATE table mysql.general_log;
```

я выполнила команду:

```
FLUSH LOGS;
```

и старый файл **general_log.txt** был удалён, на его месте появился новый, гораздо меньшего размера.